# vanniktech's emoji popup not showing

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to show up the [vanniktech's emoji popup](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji#inserting-emojis), but it's not showing:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        EmojiManager.install(IosEmojiProvider())
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayout)
        val emojiEditText = findViewById<EmojiEditText>(R.id.emojiEditText)

        val emojiPopup = EmojiPopup.Builder.fromRootView(linearLayout).build(emojiEditText)
        emojiPopup.show()    
    }
}
```

That's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiEditText
        android:id="@+id/emojiEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey @Tar did you able to find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `emojiPopup.toggle()` as per the documentation

```
final EmojiPopup emojiPopup = EmojiPopup.Builder.fromRootView(rootView).build(emojiEditText);
emojiPopup.toggle(); // Toggles visibility of the Popup.
emojiPopup.dismiss(); // Dismisses the Popup.
emojiPopup.isShowing(); // Returns true when Popup is showing.
```

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately it's not working.